# Dash Bootstrap components : Reset Modal

Tags: python, plotly, bootstrap-modal, plotly-dash

I am using dash bootstrap modal that is a form that accepts input and adds it to the datatable. When I input data and close the modal, the data is still saved and persist. I am not using `persistence` attribute, however, the data still doesn't clear.

When I reopen the modal, it automatically adds new information previously stored. Is there a way to clear all the values and reset the modal when the modal is closed?

For reference: https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/modal

```
# Add new property modal

            dbc.Button("ADD", id="add"),

            dbc.Modal(
                [
                      dbc.ModalHeader("Add new information"),
                      dbc.ModalBody(
                          [

                              dbc.InputGroup(
                                  [
                                    
                                      dcc.Input(id="Address"),


                                      dcc.Input(id="City"),


                                      dbc.Input(id="Zipcode"),

                                  ],

                                  
                              ),

                            # Close ModalBody
                            ]),

                            dbc.ModalFooter(
                                  [
                                      dbc.Button("SAVE", id="save"),
                                  ]
                            ),
                    # Close Modal
                    ],
                    id="modal-2",
             ),


# Add information
@app.callback(Output("modal-2", "is_open"),
             [
                  Input("add", "n_clicks"),
                  Input("save", "n_clicks")
             ],

             [
                  State("Address", "value"),
                  State("City","value"),
                  State("zipcode","value"),
                  State("modal-2", "is_open")
             ],
             )
def add(add_btn, save_btn, address, city, zipcode, is_open):

    if button_id == "add_btn":

        return not is_open

    elif button_id == "save_btn":

        return not is_open
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a callback where you toggle the modal using your `open` button and you set the values of your inputs to empty strings:

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("modal-2", "is_open"),
        Output("Street_Address", "value"),
        Output("City", "value"),
        Output("zipcode", "value"),
    ],
    [Input("open", "n_clicks")],
    [State("modal-2", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_modal(open_clicks, is_open):
    is_open_after_toggle = not is_open

    return (is_open_after_toggle, "", "", "")
```

Then you can create a separate callback to persist the values after your save button is clicked:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("data", "children"),
    [Input("save", "n_clicks")],
    [
        State("Street_Address", "value"),
        State("City", "value"),
        State("zipcode", "value"),
    ],
)
def save_modal_data(clicks, street_address, city, zipcode):
    # Do something with the input values...
```

---

From reading the documentation I think the `persistence` attribute applies more to persisting data after refresh (of component or page).

The documentation of the `persistence` attribute of the dropdown component says this:

> Used to allow user interactions in this component to be persisted when the component - or the page - is refreshed. If persisted is truthy and hasn't changed from its previous value, a value that the user has changed while using the app will keep that change, as long as the new value also matches what was given originally.

Comment: I updated the question with my `callback` function. The values are passed as `State` vs `Inputs`.

Comment: @kms But did you try my approach out? Are you experiencing problems with implementing the approach?  Like I mentioned in my answer, I recommend you to make 2 separate callbacks one for toggling one for saving data.